# AWS .NET SDK Update User In-Line (Embedded) Policy

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, sdk, policy

I want to update an IAM user's in-line (embedded) policy using .NET SDK. I was able to update it using following CLI command:

```
aws iam put-user-policy --user-name [username] --policy-name [policyname]
```

Please note, it is not an attached policy. It is embedded policy for the IAM user.
I want to know what is equivalent to this command in .NET SDK. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found it myself. The PutUserPolicyRequest class available in Amazon.IdentityManagement.Model namespace can be used for this purpose.